# How to split text files that are too large to open with text editors?

Tags: split, text-files, text-editor

We have a very large logfile, which we can not open with classic text editors for analysis (Notepad ++, UltraEdit, vscode, ...). Can I split the log file **easy** line by line so that I make several small logfiles that we can then display with the text editor?

Comment: UltraEdit can open any file of any size. A log file with more than 8 GiB can be opened on a PC with just 2 GiB RAM without any problem. UltraEdit should be just configured right as [large file text editor](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/large-file-handling.html) before the large file is opened. But for viewing a log file a file manager with built-in file viewer like Total Commander is the better choice. Total Commander can display contents of any file of any size with any amount of installed RAM very quickly as accessing file data in chunks like UltraEdit.

Answer (score 1):

May I introduce to you the Unix/Linux command line tools, such as `head` and `tail`?

```
head -1000 $file > part1.txt
head -2000 $file | tail -1000 > part2.txt
head -3000 $file | tail -1000 > part3.txt
head -4000 $file | tail -1000 > part4.txt
[...]
```

Comment: I think if you have the Unix/Linux command line tools on your system, that's the best answer.

Comment: I am not sure how large are your files. But Vim text editor can handle pretty large data files. (I have opened about 1 GB file without any issues). There is a GVim for windows too. Just a different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a short search I found an easy-to-use tool from [G.D.G Software](https://www.gdgsoft.com/) called [GSplit](https://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/index.aspx). The tool is free and I will tell you if it rocks.

Comment: I think that's the best answer for people looking for a GUI tool on Windows. The configuration menu offers many options. Nevertheless, @thorstenhirsch answer is best for me.

Comment: This program is only for transmitting a file in smaller pieces. It will not allow you to view the smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

`head` and `tail` are perfect for a one shot operation.

Linux power offers dozen of different solutions to meet the same result.

I believe `split` would be the command that you actually need for achieving what you want to do.

Alternatively, this task can also be automatized  using `split` (with recent gnu as older ones do not have those options), as follows, provided that your files have an (single dot) extension :

```
SplitStartIndex=0 # you can name the splitted files starting with index 0, or any other value
MAXLINES=100 # this is the split result, ie you will get 100 lines for each file and the rest for the last file
for FILE in $BASEFILES # means $BASEFILES has to be your directory, even limited to the file(s) you need to split. for ex: BASEFILES=/home/coding/mybigcodefile.c
do

    # Count the big file lines
    countlines=$(cat $FILE | wc -l)

    # split file if size > $MAXLINES=100
    if [ $countlines -gt $MAXLINES ];then

        # output_prefix = path & filename_wo_extension & PREFIX && extension
        fullfilename_wo_extension=$(echo $FILE | cut -f 1 -d '.')

        # Split the file and append the orginal extension to the output file with profix     
        split --numeric-suffixes="$SplitStartIndex" --additional-suffix=".$EXT_BASE" -l $MAXLINES $FILE $fullfilename_wo_extension

        # Backup original file, just in case ;-)
        mv $FILE "$fullfilename_wo_extension.$EXT_BCKP"

    fi

done
```